# Is there any way to generate android app link with out uploading it in play store?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to send my .apk file to my colleague for testing, instead of sending .apk file every time can I upload some where secure and generate link as we can do in **Testflight**  in IOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fabric Beta**

You can use this for sending out builds to testers. Firstly sign up to [Fabric](http://fabric.io) and add the Fabric plugin to Android Studio. Then from here follow the instructions to distribute through Beta.

Comment: Yes, I suggest you to use Fabric Beta since I used it on a couple of projects and it worked very well. And you have to be aware of its compatibility with CI services like Bitrise that you should / want to start using! :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response bro! let me check it b4 I accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

As @MichaelStoddart anticipated you could choose the Beta channel of Fabric, it works very well.

But... if you had no particular reason that didn't allow you to use the Play Store, I'd suggest you to use the Play Store Alpha & Beta channels! They are the best for Android apks.

Comment: I agree. Fabric works very well but it's a bit messy in the initial configuration phase. If I can give you an advice, use the play store channels.

Comment: The problem I have found with play store distribution is the time it take to be available, in some cases when i have uploaded a build for testers it has taken over 24 hours for that build to be indexed in the store. With Fabric the testers get an email about the build instantly and can download and test with hardly any delay

Comment: Yes, you are correct when you say that Fabric is generally faster than Play Store.. but I've never noticed such a delay for Alpha and Beta channels.. maybe I'm just lucky :) Anyway, if you only have preview purposes, it's just a matter of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link you can find suggestions:

**https://www.kumulos.com/2016/07/01/testflight-alternatives-for-google-android/**

Or other than this if you're using **git** then you can try Gitlab **Continuous Integration** where you can setup an environment and allow people to see your artificats(e.g. .apk file that you want to be tested). They can download from it and can even comment on it. Here you don't need to bother to generate your .apk every time you do some changes in your code base.

**https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/**